# Extending Herstein's Challenging Exercise to Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Anybody who has worked through Herstein's *Topics in Algebra* might remember Exercise 26 of Section 2.5 (in second edition):

> If $G$ is an abelian group containing subgroups of order $m$ and $n$, then $G$ contains a subgroup whose order is the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$.

Robert Beals has given a very nice solution in [1]. My question is whether or not we can extend the result of this exercise to modules (and if we can, to which extent). More concretely,

> Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring. If $M$ is an $R$-module that contains submodules of cardinality $m$ and
>   $n$, then must $M$ necessarily contain a submodule whose cardinality is the least
>   common multiple of $m$ and $n$?

Since abelian groups can be viewed as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, this generalizes the above situation. Now, I am guessing this fails for arbitrary rings. I would be especially interested to know the conclusion if $R$ is Noetherian. (I think if $R$ is a PID, the conclusion follows, but I have no proof for this. Beals' proof uses purely group-theoretic concepts some of which I cannot generalize to modules).

Thanks for your time :)

[1] Beals, Robert. "On Orders of Subgroups in Abelian Groups: An Elementary Solution of an Exercise of Herstein." The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 116, No. 10 (Dec., 2009), pp. 923-926

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be missing something, but can't you show this as follows?

To prove the result for  (additive) abelian groups, we can first show that a finite subgroup is the direct sum of its primary components (which are also its Sylow subgroups), and then show that the sum $H = H_1+H_2$ of two finite subgroups of coprime order $m$, $n$ has order $mn$. By combining these two techniques, for any two finite subgroups, we can construct a subgroup of order equal to the least common multiple of their orders: we first decompose both subgroups into primary components, and then recombine the primary components appropriately from the two subgroups.

We can do the same thing with submodules. An $R$-module $M$ of finite order $n$ is also an additive abelian group of finite order $n$, and so is the direct sum of its primary components $M_p$, for the primes $p$ dividing $n$, where $M_p$ can be defined as $M_p = \{m \in M \mid p^am=0 {\ \rm for\ some\ } a \ge 0 \}$. Then $M_p$ is also an $R$-submodule, because $m \in M_p \Rightarrow p^am=0 \Rightarrow p^arm=0$ for any $r \in R$, so $rm \in M_p$.

Secondly, if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are finite $R$-submodules of coprimes orders $m$, $n$, then, as an abelian group, $M_1+M_2$ has order $mn$, but $M_1+M_2$ is also an $R$-submodule.

Comment: I think this is fine. Beals was apparently motivated to cite only results from earlier in Herstein than the location of the exercise, so that most of the paper consists of spelling out the details of the same proof you give.

Comment: Thank you for this superb solution! I guess the underlying ring $R$ is actually irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Yes, the ring doesn't even need to be commutative.