# If a commutative group has subgroups of order $m$ and $n$ , then it has a subgroup of order $\space$l.c.m.$(m,n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Without using ideas from "Normal subgroups" and "Quotient groups" how do we prove the following statement ; "If a commutative group has subgroups of order $m$ and $n$ , then it has a subgroup of order   $\space$l.c.m.$(m,n)$ ."  ?

Comment: This is an extremely hard exercise from Herstein (I think), that the author himself did not actually know a solution for. Someone managed to find a solution at some point, but it all seems fairly artificial to me to require something like this.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: Do you know the solution that "Someone managed to find...at some point" ? It would really be helpful.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453352/extending-hersteins-challenging-exercise-to-modules has a reference to the paper with the solution, and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19092/on-order-of-subgroups-in-abelian-groups has some discussion of it.